# Mac Mini has static screen when wake from sleep

Tags: macos, hdmi, sleep, dvi, mac-mini

Intermittently, about once a day, when waking my Mac Mini M2 from sleep, I'll get this screen instead of the lock screen:

[image: Static Screen on wake from sleep mac mini m2]

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Turning the monitor off and on again sometimes works. Plugging the HDMI cable out and back in again is annoying. It also comes back to normal if I wait about 20 seconds.

For reference, I'm using a 1080p DVI monitor. I'm using an HDMI-DVI cable. I've tried 2 cables, a 2m one and a 1.5m one. My screen is too far away to use a 1 m cable. Safe mode makes no difference.

A brief google search indicates this is a common issue with the HDMI port on the Mac Mini, especially but not exclusive to 1080p DVI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Permanent solution:**

Use a USB-C-DVI cable. I've never had an issue with this cable. But this is annoying, because you lose a Thunderbolt port, and the M2 Mac Minis only have 2 to start with. Also, Night Shift scheduling breaks for some reason.

**Workaround I settled for, sticking with HDMI-DVI:**

When you see static, hitting the Esc key will turn the screen off. You can then hit any other key to bring up the lock screen as normal. And I get to keep using the USB-C port.